# Git Clone from Github to Network Drive

Tags: git, networking, drive

I am trying to set up version control using Git on my work computer. I am expected to keep all my files on our network drive. When I run

```
git clone https://github.com/account_name/myrepo_r.git
```

from Git Bash in my folder on the network drive /y/test I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo_r'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
error: unable to append to 'Y:/test/myrepo_r/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD': Bad file descriptor
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to 'Y:/test/myrepo_r/.git/logs/HEAD': Bad file descriptor
```

When I run the same command from a directory on my desktop, I have no issues.

Is there a way to checkout my code onto my network drive?

Comment: Is this standard git for windows, and is your network drive an ordinary windows network shared folder? If otherwise, could you please clarify what you're working with?

Comment: Yes, this is standard git for windows and an ordinary windows network shared folder

Comment: Did you find solution for this? we facing the same problem.